# Java Web Service SOAP with Tomcat

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, tomcat8

I have this problem:

I'm created a web service in NetBeans IDE and TomCat as a server. This is my web service:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "wsEagle_au")
public class wsEagle_au 
{
    private pSession psession;
    @WebMethod(operationName = "log_in")
    public ArrayList log_in(@WebParam(name = "NICK_USER") String 
    NICK_USER,@WebParam(name = "HASH_USER") String HASH_USER)throws 
    Exception
    {
        psession=new pSession();
        return psession.log_in(NICK_USER.toUpperCase(), HASH_USER);
    }
}
```

and this is the method where the arraylist is filled:

```
public ArrayList log_in(mSession msession) throws JSONException
{
   try
   {
       cfunctions=new cFunctions(msession.getNICK_USER());
       msession.setHASH_USER(cfunctions.crypt(msession.getHASH_USER()));
       res_array=new ArrayList();
       res_jobject=new JSONObject();
       sqlquery="sqlQuery";
       sql.getConnection();
       sql.prepareStatement(sqlquery);
       sql.setString(1,msession.getNICK_USER());
       sql.setString(2,msession.getHASH_USER());
       datareader=sql.executeQuery();
       if(datareader!=null&&datareader.next()){
          res_jobject.put("ID_USER",datareader.getInt("ID_USER"));
          res_jobject.put("NAME_USER",datareader.getString("NAME_USER"));
          res_jobject.put("CNCIASIDN",datareader.getInt("CNCIASIDN"));
          res_jobject.put("SUSUUSID",datareader.getInt("SUSUUSID"));
          res_array.add(res_jobject);
       }
       else
       {
           //Password o User incorrect
           res_array.clear();
           res_jobject=new JSONObject();
           res_jobject.put("error","002");
           res_array.add(res_jobject);
       }  
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       //Inesperate error.
       res_array=new ArrayList();
       res_jobject=new JSONObject();
       res_jobject.put("error","002");
       res_array.add(res_jobject);
   }
    return res_array;
}
```

When I tested with SOAP UI, I obtained this response:
[SOAPUI RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr0iM.jpg)

How can I return the arraylist?

Comment: It looks like your response image has been chopped off. What's the full response?

Comment: It's all the response, nothing is missing.